# laravel multi-level many to many

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 models, Industry, Category, Machine and they are linked as following

- Industry can have multiple Categories, and a Category can be in only
  one Industry (industry Id stored in category table)
- A category can have multiple machines, and a machine can be in multiple Categories (using pivot table)

Problem : I want to show all machines in an industry, how i can do that?

What I did so far : I retrieved all category ids related to a specific industry like : $industry->categories()->pluck("id"). I don't know what I can do next to get all machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Industry` model relation:

```php
class Industry {
    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

`Category` model relation:

```php
class Category {
    public function indusry(){
        return $this->hasOne(Industry::class);
    }

    public function machines(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Machine::class);
    }
}
```

`Machine` model relation:

```php
class Machine {
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

you can use `whereHas` method like this:

```php
$machines = Machine::whereHas('categories', function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('indusry', function($sub_query) {
        $sub_query->where('name', {your_industry});
    });
});
```

Comment: I have to store "category_id", in machines tables to make that work. Which I can't because I have many to many relationship between categories and machines. Which is achieved via pivot table

Comment: you don't any need to store `category_id`, when you using from `hasManyThrough` relation, this can provide a relation between `machines` and `industries` and you can access all machines in an industry like: `$industry->machines()`

Comment: I am getting this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'machines.category_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `machines` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `machines`.`category_id` where `categories`.`industry_id` = 1)

Comment: oh sorry, it's my mistake, I will update the answer.

Comment: my tables
---
industries : id, name
---
categories : id, industry_id, name
---
machines : id, name
---
category_machine: category_id, machine_id
---
and relationships are defined as you suggested

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the results using your answer, but with a little change as below $industry = Industry::where("slug","=",$industry_slug)->first();

            $categories = $industry->categories()->pluck('id');

            $machines = Machine::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categories) {
                return $q->whereIn('id', $categories);
            })->paginate(20);

Answer (score -1):

$categories = $industry->categories()->pluck("id");
$machines = App\Machine::query()->whereIn('category_id', $categories)->get();

Comment: I have to store "category_id", in machines tables to make that work. Which I can't because I have many to many relationship between categories and machines. Which is achieved via pivot table

Comment: If you use polymorphic  operation morphToMany, morphedByMany, you can handle it efficiently. You can follow the example- 
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-many-to-many-polymorphic-relationship-tutorialexample.html